# Can't ssh to ec2 instance with secpanel

Tags: ssh, aws

I am trying to get my secpanel to work with my ec2 instance.  I can ssh to it from a terminal like this:

```
shh -i UbuntuKey.pem ubuntu@x.x.x.x
```

that works fine,  but when I set the same thing up in secpanel,  I get a brief look at the terminal, then it closes. 
I have the host set correctly,  the user is ubuntu, and the Identity is pointing to the UbuntuKey.pem  and using port 22.

Am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the permission 0400 on the `.pem` file.

1) Open a terminal. 
2) go to the folder where the `.pem` file is. 
3) type:

```
chmod 0400 pemFileName.pem
```

Comment: How do you do this? It is required that you include the steps to achieve this in your answer, as it is this is a suggestion and should be a comment.

Comment: I can't comment since I am new here and need a 50 reputation to comment. To set permission: 1) Go to terminal. 2) go to the folder where the pem file is. 3) type: chmod 0400 pemFileName.pem

Comment: I am not asking you how to do it, I am saying you need to update your answer with the instructions, click edit under your answer and add the information.